# How to write a nested json data in python

Tags: python, json, excel

I am writing a script to convert excel sheet into json format. Sheet looks like below image:

[image]

In above sheet, row 1 is the name of the key and row 2 contains its values. 
Yellow colored columns will come under a nested json. I need to convert it in below format:

```
{
    "Data1": "Value1",
    "BigData": "{'Data2':'Value2', 'Data3':'Value3', 'Data4':'Value4'}",
    "Data5": "Value5"
}
```

But the issue is, I am not able to understand what kind of nested array `BigData` is and how can we do this in python. I am only able to convert the excel sheet in below format:

```
{
    "Data1": "Value1",
    "BigData": {
        "Data2" : "Value2", 
        "Data3" : "Value3", 
        "Data4" : "Value4"
    },
    "Data5": "Value5"
}
```

I am using `xlrd` python package and below is the code:

```
data = dict()

data[sheet.cell_value(0, 0)] = str(sheet.cell_value(1, 0))
big_data = { sheet.cell_value(0, 1): str(sheet.cell_value(1, 1)),
                sheet.cell_value(0, 2): str(sheet.cell_value(1, 2))
                sheet.cell_value(0, 3): str(sheet.cell_value(1, 3))
               }
data["BigData"] = big_data
data[sheet.cell_value(0, 4)] = str(sheet.cell_value(1, 4))

jsonData = json.dumps(data)

with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
     json.dump(data, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue. THanks

Comment: The second JSON example is perfectly valid. The first one uses a _string_, not a nested object.

Comment: @ForceBru For some reason, I have to convert it into the first example json format. Is there any way we can do it.? Thanks

Comment: Well, you can simply convert `big_data` to a string: `data["BigData"] = str(big_data)`

Comment: Use data["BigData"] = str(big_data) instead of data["BigData"] = big_data

Comment: @ForceBru  Thank you. That was a very simple solution which I didnt thought. Please answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

On the conversion we have 3 cases:

lists
dicts (new object)

### bool, int, float and str

```
import json

class AppConfiguration(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            with open("cfg.json") as fh:
                data = json.loads(fh.read())
        else:
            data = dict(data)

        for key, val in data.items():
            setattr(self, key, self.compute_attr_value(val))

    def compute_attr_value(self, value):
        if type(value) is list:
            return [self.compute_attr_value(x) for x in value]
        elif type(value) is dict:
            return AppConfiguration(value)
        else:
            return value
```

Now the key, value pairs are attributes - objects.

```
instance = AppConfiguration()
>>>instance.key
'value'

>>>instance.list[4].key
1

>>> instance.object.key.key
1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?